How to find/ get work in office
I am a senior principle engineer or Enterprise architect at a medium sized company. I am working here for nearly 3years. We used to have weekly meetings with managers and directors to know their pain points and I was able to address couple of them diligently. I used to have healthy 1-1s with my manager and we used to decide on course of action. Things were pretty good.
Recently (3months back) my manager got changed (why? nobody knows. Not even senior management knows it. Lets call him (B). B went around selling weird ideas to the CEOs and got earned appreciations. I was asked to execute the project --lets call it (p), and I questioned back the idea and feasibility. No answers. No questions either back to me. I was removed from the project. A junior resource is pulled in and he is doing the project. The project is now stuck. Not going anywhere.
I had atleast 3 1-1s with my new manager(B). I dont get any deterministic/ concrete projects/ roadmap. I started questioning the little thoughts presented by (B) in the 1-1s, and he started saying that I may be placed into project (p --which is stuck). Meaning I need to work and make sense of the little thoughts and bring something to the table. Even if I do it, I am not sure how much of a use it will be to the company.
So, the question is... How do i proceed with this situation. I tried to find jobs in market, but for my experience (19y) getting one will take 8-10months. Other thought I have is to talk to manager of (B). But short-circuiting B may offend him (B).
So what more can i do? I want some meaningful work for next 3-4 months.

Unfortunately, we cannot make decisions for you. It seems that you already have all the information - but you do not like the alternatives. Unfortunately, you are the one who needs to decide on the path ahead.

Put bluntly: you are one of the most senior technical staff at your employer. Your job is to be driving the roadmap, not waiting for someone to hand it to you on a plate.
Do what needs to be done. Ask for forgiveness later, if necessary.

I think there's a typo, Ask instead of All?

You are correct, thank you
